# Dealing with large structured data sets

Tags: database, dataset, lisp, common-lisp

What I'm asking is rather a methodology, than a concrete solution. I will start by describing the situation I found challenging, and will then proceed to the question. Hope it makes more sense to do it this way.

I'm dealing with data extracted from natural language. This data must be later analysed against a sort of "knowledge base" (it's quoted because it's not really a knowledge base, I'll get to it later). The knowledge base is large, its volume, so far theoretically, but soon practically will surpass what is possible to store in-memory. My two concerns are these:

- Moving the data over to a database server will mean speed reduction by a factor... well, I don't know what factor, but it could be easily several orders of magnitude. I.e. a task of finding a piece of data in an object native to the runtime located in memory is significantly faster, then querying the database.
- The entire huge volume of data is not required at any one time. In fact, only a very small fraction is used, so, perhaps some caching could aid the problem. I'm actually hoping that someone already faced this problem and caching was the right answer.

The "knowledge base" is so far just a complex data structure, which can be queried about in a similar way you would query a database by using some query language. I.e. it is not a simple lookup value by key operation, it requires multiple sub-queries to identify an object as matching the given criteria.

Just to give you more concrete example of what I'm trying to do. Unlike `langutils`, I'm trying to come up with a parser, which I'm calling "predictive parser", sorry if the term is already taken and means something else :) The main idea is that instead of assigning POS tags to words, and then iteratively correcting the original assumption by applying a set of rules to the inferred information, I'm trying to do it in a way, that given a certain prefix, the engine would generate a continuation, based on its "learned knowledge". I.e. suppose the knowledge base learned that the prefix "I could " is almost certainly followed by a verb phrase. And so the parser would assume the verb phrase and parse it as such, unless it hits an error. The difficult part is finding the proper prefix. The bad thing is that prefices like "I will " and "Thou shalt" will get equal priority, i.e. they would be checked for the match in the same order, either random, alphabetical etc. The idea is though that during the knowledge acquisition the knowledge base would learn to store and look up the information in such way, that the most likely prefices would be looked up first, and the least likely prefices would not be even loaded initially.

This is the concept somewhat similar to how CPU cache works. So, if what I wrote is too long: I'm looking for a data structure, that functions like CPU cache, where what's currently cached resides in memory, and what isn't is stored in a database, or as a file etc.

PS. Sorry for my collection of tags. I feel like it's not really describing my question. You are welcome to adjust it, if you know where the question belongs.

Comment: This is a hard design problem. If performance is not important and maintainability (of the data) is important, I'd say go for the database. If your key process is tagging, a round-trip to the database per token would be the typical cost (for query only, updates are harder). For real-time Markov thingies, the data **needs** to be in core.

Comment: A two level structure - prefixes and rules usage - where the prefixes are 1:M to the rules, and both are indexed may help. The prefix index is normal, but the rules usage index is dynamic and weighted, and is ordered by the weight within the prefix. The learning process would populate a) the rules usage table b) the rules usage index c) the weighting in the index and d) the prefix table and the prefix index. This structure could be cached - the two indexes and the rule set appropriate to a small set of prefixes. I do not know if such a weighted index structure exists.

Comment: Sounds like Datomic will fit your bill very well. It has a caching model very similar to what you describe, and it has a query system based on datalog.

Comment: You can still use an all-memory implementation if you have the means to build a networked cluster, and carve out the knowledge chunks so that they can be distributed across different nodes in the cluster. Check out this work as an example of an Erlang implementation: http://act-r.psy.cmu.edu/papers/926/Douglass(2).pdf

Answer (score 1):

If we just consider this part:

> The idea is though that during the knowledge acquisition the knowledge
>   base would learn to store and look up the information in such way,
>   that the most likely prefices would be looked up first, and the least
>   likely prefices would not be even loaded initially.

then, if I understood you correctly, you're dealing with the task of handling n-grams. As in your situation you're not putting any explicit limits on the prefixes, it can be assumed, that the generally reasonable limits apply, and those are 4-5 word n-grams. There's a lot of such n-grams: from a real-world corpus you'd easily get gigabytes of data. But even if you limit yourself to only 3-grams, you'll still get at least a couple of gigabytes, unless you perform some clever pre-processing, that will somehow separate the "good" n-grams. (Coupled with proper smoothing this may be a feasible solution).

The bad news about n-grams besides their size is that they are distributed by the [Zipf's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law), which basically means, that caching won't be very useful.

So, I'd just put the data into some fast database on the local machine (maybe, some variant of [dbm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dbm)). If you can fit it all in memory, maybe, Memcached or Redis will be faster.

Comment: Surely, for the case of "the" caching would work, but the general problem is that you'll get the biggest volume of requests to the n-grams, which have medium frequency. So if you cache say 20% of most frequent n-grams, you'll get 20%, maybe 30%, of requests to them. While a good cache use-case is when it will be able to serve 80% of requests with 20% of most frequently used items. (Yet my understanding of this subject may be not precise and incomplete - although I have some practical experience, which somewhat confirms it).